# How to minimize a group of rows in a DataGridView so they take up less space?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, grouping

Having a problem with my `DataGridView` in that there is a lot of repeated or very similar data and once there start to be hundreds of rows it gets very unwieldy.

I looked around for some custom controls that allow for grouping but the ones I found either cost money, are old, are too complex to warrant switching for this one thing, or don't work with my existing codebase (incompatible types, etc.)

Preferably I'd be able to do this with a regular `DataGridView`. I'd like to have a menu item button that when clicked, takes the selected rows and turns them in to one row (while preserving the data and providing some sort of visual cue that the rows are compressed). When clicked again the row would be restored.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to accomplish this? I suppose I could have a `List` of a collection of `DataGridViewRow`s and some way of saving the corresponding indicies or something gross like that but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you considered what you are presenting to your users?  Is it possible to present less data?

Comment: @BryanCrosby: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do but allowing collapsing of selected rows. No I cannot modify the data in any while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use a 3rd party control or custom control, the poor man's solution for this is simple.

Let's assume your data looks like this:

```
public class CustomData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What you might display to your users could be this:

```
List<CustomData> data = new List<CustomData>()
                                        {
                                            new CustomData { Id = 1, Name = "Test", Type = "Group1"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 2, Name = "Test", Type = "Group1"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 3, Name = "Test", Type = "Group1"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 4, Name = "Test", Type = "Group2"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 5, Name = "Test", Type = "Group2"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 6, Name = "Test", Type = "Group2"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 7, Name = "Test", Type = "Group3"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 8, Name = "Test", Type = "Group3"},
                                            new CustomData { Id = 9, Name = "Test", Type = "Group3"},
                                        };
var dataDisplayedToUser = data.GroupBy(g => g.Type).Select(p => p.Key);
```

Which in this case would be:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

When a user wants to double-click a row in your grid, you could present them with simply another modal data grid with the following sub-set of data.

```
string dataValue = theGroupTheUserSelected // from your grid
var specificData = data.Where(f => f.Type == theGroupTheUserSelected);
```

You end up with less data displayed to the user, which is easier on the eyes and easier to understand.